# Looking for ngFor and function with arguments at the same time examples ie Stackblitz

Tags: angular

I am working on a project where I had a ngFor with the same input repeating each day.

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #newForm="ngForm" >
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input type="number" id="price" name="price" [(ngModel)]="model.price" #price="ngModel">
  </form>
</div>
<button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

I am confused on function with parameters. Is there any example I can see because on my project, if I modify an input, the 2 others change, but on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-swrr7s?file=src/app/date-range-picker-overview-example.html), I have 3 distincts input.
Well, I don't put the ngModel in it but the idea is there.

Why on my project, do I have the 3 same inputs? I might have never understood the function with arguments if so.

In my ts file:

```
  form: FormGroup;
  newForm: FormGroup;
  calendars: any[];
  calendar: any[];
  today = Date.now();
  days: any[];
  price: number;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({});
    this.newForm = new FormGroup({});

    this.calendars = [{ start: "", end: "" }];

    this.days = [
      { name: 1 },
      { name: 2 },
      { name: 3 }
    ];

    this.price = 1;
  }

  addCalendar() {
    this.calendars.push(this.calendar);
    console.log(this.calendars);
  }

  removeCalendar() {
    if (this.calendars.length > 1) {
      this.calendars.pop();
      console.log(this.calendars);
    }
  }

  model = new Product(18);

  onSubmit() { 

    console.log(this.newForm.value);
    }
```

Edit: I included my code directly.

Comment: You could use a ngSwitch inside the ngFor for different templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using `#newForm="ngForm"` then no need to declare in ts file. After that just add `price` key in your day array like

```
this.days = [
  { name: 1, price: 0 },
  { name: 2, price: 0 },
  { name: 3, price: 0 }
];
```

After that just add this `(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newForm.value)"` in `form` tag. In input filed add `[(ngModel)]="day.price"` to set value on specific price key.

In ts file on `submit` function add parameter you want:

```
onSubmit(value: any) { 
    console.log(value);
}
```

Here is full code:

**HTML**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newForm.value)" #newForm="ngForm" >
<div *ngFor="let day of days; let i = index">
    <label for="price">Price:</label>
    <input type="number" id="price{{i}}" name="price{{i}}"    <!-- don't forgot to add name and id with index -->
    [(ngModel)]="day.price">
</div>
<button class="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
  // form: FormGroup;          // no need to add this
  // newForm: FormGroup;     // no need to add this
  calendars: any[];
  calendar: any[];
  today = Date.now();
  days: any[];
  // price: number;      // no need to add this

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // this.form = new FormGroup({});      // no need to add this
    // this.newForm = new FormGroup({});   // no need to add this

    this.calendars = [{ start: "", end: "" }];

    this.days = [
      { name: 1, price: 0 },
      { name: 2, price: 0 },
      { name: 3, price: 0 }
    ];

    // this.price = 1;
  }

  addCalendar() {
    this.calendars.push(this.calendar);
    console.log(this.calendars);
  }

  removeCalendar() {
    if (this.calendars.length > 1) {
      this.calendars.pop();
      console.log(this.calendars);
    }
  }

  model = new Product(18);

  onSubmit(value: any) { 
    console.log(value);
  }
```

Comment: you saved me. I don't know how I went missing on another let in the ngFor and to use interpolation in the id and name. That's things I didn't think about and thought were forbidden. Thanks a lot.